# MPMediaPropertyPredicate - filter MPMediaQuery by songs duration

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, mpmediaquery

I am fetching music tracks from user's music library like this:

```
    let query = MPMediaQuery.songs()
    let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: false, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem)
    
    query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)
    
    if let fetchedSongs = query.items {
       // Do something with tracks
    }
```

However, I don't need songs longer than 5 minutes. I tried to add a new predicate `MPMediaPropertyPredicate` to filter out all tracks longer than 5 minutes but with no success - I am not sure what to use in the `value` parameter and if I can use a condition like `"duration < 300"` in a simple `NSPredicate`.

Comment: I guess that `MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: 300, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration, comparisonType: .greaterThan)`would have worked, but since the comparisonType only allow `.contains` or `.equalsTo`, I'mt not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the query and filter the results yourself. Here's code from my own app that gets all the very short songs:

```
let query = MPMediaQuery.songs()
// always need to filter out songs that aren't present
let isPresent = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value:false,
                                         forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem,
                                         comparisonType:.equalTo)
query.addFilterPredicate(isPresent)
guard let items = query.items else {return} //

let shorties = items.filter { //
    let dur = $0.playbackDuration
    return dur < 30
}
```